# 招待メールの文言

Tags: 討議, 完了, 翻訳

他のユーザーを招待したい場合、メインページと質問ページの右側に次のフォームがあります：

> [image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

これを利用して招待を送ると下記のメールがきます：

> 拝啓、
>
> $ユーザー名$から、あなたが スタック・オーバーフロー Q&A サイトに適したエキスパートであると推薦を受けました。
>
> $ユーザー名$からの別のメッセージ: $メッセージ$
>
> この新しい [Stack Exchange Q&A サイト](http://stackexchange.com/)は現在プライベート
>   ベータですが、他のユーザーからの推薦により、あなたに極秘アクセスをご提供しています。早期にコミュニティを発展させるためにご協力ください。
>
> [アクセスの許可を要求する](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

これで大丈夫ですか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

拝啓はとても畏まった言い方ですし極秘はtop secret的なニュアンスなので要らないと思います。

> $ユーザー名$から、あなたが スタック・オーバーフロー Q&A サイトに適したエキスパートであると推薦を受けました。
>
> $ユーザー名$からのメッセージ: $メッセージ$
>
> 新しい Stack Exchange Q&A サイトは現在プライベート
>   ベータですが、他のユーザーからの推薦により、あなたにアクセス権をご提供しています。コミュニティを立ち上げるためにご協力ください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。このメッセージを使いました。「拝啓」は英語で「Hello,」だったため、「こんにちは！」に変えました。yoshi0309の回答の元に、メッセージの前に改行も入れました。ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 1):

- 招待フォームですがメールアドレスを入力すべきであることがわかりにくいです。上部の入力欄に、hoge@example.com のようにグレーで入れるか、メッセージにメールアドレスと明示すると良いと思います。
- メールの文面ですが、「$ユーザー名$からの別のメッセージ: $メッセージ$」の箇所について「別の」は不要かと思います。
- 同じくメールの文面の「$ユーザー名$からの別のメッセージ: $メッセージ$」ですが、「$メッセージ$」の前に改行を入れたほうが読みやすいかと思います。

> $ユーザー名$からのメッセージ: \r\n $メッセージ$

Comment: 灰色のテキストは開発者が必要で、後で検討します。他は適用済みです。